# How to enable autoplay on video in master-detail view in AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, html, google-chrome

In my master-detail view I have embedded a video (HTML5 video tag) in every single detail view. Now I need to autoplay HTML5 video in my browser (Chrome v59, Android) when the detail view is selected. For some reason when the master-detail view is loaded at the beginning, the video in the first detail view is automatically starting. When I am selecting another detail view via md-sidenav the video doesn't start. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  javascript code to play your video again

```
document.getElementById('video').play();
```

Comment: If somebody is interested: As far as I know now, chrome demands some user interaction before autoplaying a video